# How to define the execution order of interceptor in Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I define an interceptor and register it in a class (annotated with Configuration) which extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`; however, I also use some third-party libraries which also define some interceptors. I want my interceptor to be the last one in the interceptor execution chain. It seems there is no way to enforce this. How to define the execution order of interceptor in Spring Boot application?

Comment: Add `@Order`  or implement `Ordered` and give it a high order. It isn't so much the order of execution but the order of registering the interceptors and is basic spring mvc and not different for spring boot.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask whether I should add @Order on interceptor class? Or should I add Order annotation on the configuration class which register the interceptor?

Comment: The configuration class, the one extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. The detection mechanism should honor the ordering.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think you should post these comments as an answer.

Comment: Even after using @Order on WebMvcConfigurationAdapter class my custom handler interceptor is getting executed first not the third party interceptor. Any thing else which we need to configure here ?

Answer (score 12):

If we've Multiple Interceptors, Instead of `@Order` Annotation we can do as below.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addWebRequestInterceptor(new WebRequestInterceptor() {
                //Overrides
            }).order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registry
           .addWebRequestInterceptor(new WebRequestInterceptor() {
                //Overrides
            }).order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

Comment: i saw the source code,this order method was added since spring 5.0,when i use 1.5.x of spring boot(4.3.x version of spring framework ),how to do?

Comment: [`.order()`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.23.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.html#order-int-) is there since Spring 4.3.23.

Answer (score 0):

All Feign clients become proxies, so there is only one way to change the order of the request interceptors. But you cannot use it, because if you change the proxy to SGLIB, it will not work.

```
    if(bean instanceof YoursFeignClientBean) {
        Class<Proxy> superclass = (Class<Proxy>) bean.getClass().getSuperclass();
        Field h =  superclass.getDeclaredField("h");
        h.setAccessible(true);

        // its FeignInvocationHandler
        InvocationHandler ih = (InvocationHandler) ReflectionUtils.getField(h, bean);
        Field dispatch = ih.getClass().getDeclaredField("dispatch");
        dispatch.setAccessible(true);

        Map<Method, InvocationHandlerFactory.MethodHandler> map =
                (Map<Method, InvocationHandlerFactory.MethodHandler>) dispatch.get(ih);

        for (Method method : map.keySet()) {
            InvocationHandlerFactory.MethodHandler handler = map.get(method);
            Field requestInterceptors = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("requestInterceptors");
            requestInterceptors.setAccessible(true);

            List<RequestInterceptor> interceptorList = (List<RequestInterceptor>)
                    ReflectionUtils.getField(requestInterceptors, handler);

            RequestInterceptor ri =  interceptorList.stream().filter(t -> t.getClass().getName().startsWith(YoursFeignConfig.class.getName())).findFirst().get();

            // reorder
            interceptorList.remove(ri);
            interceptorList.add(ri);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

According to my experience, Interceptors are adding a stack. For this reason you should addRegister above which one you want before calling than other.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Elaborate, show, examples. Please